# How to add custom tag on the top of each bar of Bar-charts in Echarts

Tags: vue.js, echarts

[image]
Is there any way to implment that putting a custom tag which is not yAxis value on the top of each bar? I have checked all bar-charts demo on Echarts offcial site, and no demo fulfilled my needs.

Comment: How you generate tags, or it is static for all bar ?

Comment: It's dynamically generated with object received from back end, your answer solve my promblem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `formatter` option for `label`:

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top',
        formatter: function(data){
            return 'Bar #' + (data.dataIndex+1)
        }
      },
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};
```